# How can a javascript function be fired when a user types text into an input field or pastes text into it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("input[id^='question']").live('keyup',function(ev){
    id=this.id.substr(8);
    if (ajaxCallTimeoutID != null)
    clearTimeout(ajaxCallTimeoutID);
ajaxCallTimeoutID = setTimeout(function(){subjectivecheck(id)}, 1000);
}); 
});
```

There is a problem. When a user pastes text into an input field, the function above can not be fired. How to solve this problem?

Comment: subjectivecheck() is only wanted when a user stops typing for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onchange` event is what you want here.  It fires when the textbox loses focus (blur) and has had its value changed since it received focus.  It takes care of the paste problem.

So instead of `.live('keyup',` use  `live('change'`.

This is as good as it gets, without using some ridiculous interval polling.  And just for the purpose of context, be aware that any user can disable Javascript in the browser whenever they feel like it.

Comment: But if a user is keeping typing? I only want to check the value when a user stops typing

Answer (score 0):

The Paste (`onpaste`) event is not standard - it is AFAIK supported only in Internet Explorer (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536955(VS.85).aspx)

The change (`onchange` handlder) event is standard - but that will only fire if the value of the textbox changed in the time between gaining and losing focus - i.o.w. detecting change requires the textbox to lose focus.

What you could do, is use `setInterval()` (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to poll the value of the textbox, and compare it with the previous value.

Comment: I only want to check user input when the user stops typing.

Comment: In which case `onchange` is probably what you want.

Comment: No, but what if the textbox has not lost focus but a user stops typing. For example, a user stops typing but the input cursor is still in the textbox?

Comment: You can clear the current timeout whenever you detect a key press, and of course set a new one. That way, you can prevent premature change detection.

In addition, you can start adding the intervals only after the ttextbox gains focus, and clear it when on blur event. This will make the app more responsive as no timeis wasted polling the textbox.

Comment: Roland, I think the polling is necessary for the mouse paste or edit->undo in the browser

Comment: Mic, darn - I forgot about the edit/undo path. So there is no way around it, you have to keep polling the frecking thing.

Answer (score 0):

At the onfocus event on the field, you can start a timer to check if the field value has changed.

And at onblur, clear that timer.

The paste with ctrl+v is ok with onkeyup, but not with the mouse right click or with a browser undo.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the only problem. Even if you could catch cut and paste reliably on all browsers, which you can't, there are still more ways of putting content in a form field. For example on some platforms dragging a file to an input will put the pathname in, with no event for you to catch. Or a user might do right-click-Undo to change the contents. Or Delete. Or select some text from the input or another input and drag-and-drop it in. And probably many more I haven't thought of.

If you want to be informed of all changes to a form field more quickly than `onchange`, I'm afraid there is no alternative but to constantly monitor the `value` of the element in a polling `setInterval`.